# Add to wordpress registration page

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Im making a plugin for BuddyPress and want to add a "register with Linkedin" button to the registration page underneath or above the registration form. I cant figure out how to add to this page. I foud a way to add fields to the form but this is not what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several appropriate actions, that you can use. Please refer to `/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/register.php`

In my opinion `<?php do_action( 'bp_before_register_page' ); ?>` or `<?php do_action( 'bp_after_register_page' ); ?>` is what you might need.